# BadDigest when calling the PutObject operation s3 boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

This code works fine

```
import boto3

def upload(request):
    try:
        get_file = request.POST['file'].file
        d_filename = 'foo-'+uuid.uuid4().hex
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3.Bucket('Bucket_name').put_object(Key=d_filename, Body=get_file, ContentType=ContentType)
        return d_filename
    except Exception, e:
        log.error(str(e))
        return 'error'
```

but when i want to put md5 hash of file in filename it throws error- "An error occurred (BadDigest) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 4): The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received."

```
import boto3
import hashlib

def upload(request):
    try:
        get_file = request.POST['file'].file
        d_filename = 'foo-'+str(hashlib.md5(get_file.read()).hexdigest())
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3.Bucket('Bucket_name').put_object(Key=d_filename, Body=get_file, ContentType=ContentType)
        return d_filename
    except Exception, e:
        log.error(str(e))
        return 'error'
```

I am not trying to calculate md5 of file already uploaded or trying to set it for  file but want md5 in name of the file.

Comment: @snakecharmerb base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5(open('Local/Path/To/File').read()).digest()) does not help.

Comment: `get_file.read()` could be leaving `get_file` pointed to EOF.  I'll bet you need to seek it back to offset 0.  Wild guess: add `get_file.seek(0,0)` between the time you build your hash and the time you use `put_object()`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks michael it helped.